# Angular 5 is on idle too much time

Tags: angular

So i'm working on a web running with Angular 5.
The problem is that there is a gap (nothing is happening) in the loading process.

I have no idea what to do? what can cause this?

I'm using the following line to build the project: `ng build --prod --output-hashing all`

**Network tab sc:**
[image]

**Performance tab profiling sc:**
[image]

Comment: How do you serve your bundle ?

Comment: Hi ... what about the size of yours js ? . .could it be parsing and other stuff on js file? .. do you use lazy load in your solution?